Why ignore beginner questions about Kali Linux?
Original question here as well as coped here for reference:

I've downloaded 64bit Virtualbox Kali Linux and after launching it I am almost immediately presented with the login screen. I've tried the default virtualbox credentials, kali/kali, root/toor and all blank. Nothing worked and I can't find the answer anywhere.

This question was not well received. My post was downvoted immediately and people told me that if I asked this question I should use a different distro, but nobody actually answered my question and it was mostly ignored by most.
The password is osboxes.org and this is for all distros that you download using the link from the Virtual Box website.
I would've ran into the same problem with any other distro, but because I ran into it with kali I get down voted and ignored. Great community.
If someone has trouble with the setup you could answer their question (unless maybe the problem is Kali Linux specific) and recommend them to use a different distro.
Ignoring/downvoting people because they're "beginners" is going to discourage them from using Linux, confuse them and make them feel negatively about the Linux community.
So why ignore and even downvote beginner questions about Kali Linux?

Hello. 1. This is not a Linux community. 2. You shouldn't duplicate closed questions as you will get question blocked. Also, generally you should read rules of communities you are new at. 3. This website is for answering specific and interesting questions, not "How to log in into Kali Linux?" type of ones. You provided close to 0 details on that one and people found it not good enough for the site - edit it and include info about what exactly you used and how, step by step.

Also note this question alread has duplicates here: https://superuser.com/questions/1522358/incorrect-password-on-first-login-to-kali-linux-in-virtualbox

The password "osboxes.org" is related to a site of the same name. Without the information that you downloaded from this site, nobody can know the password. We often get beginners' questions referring to Kali, which is a distribution targeted to Linux experts.

Besides the reasons specific to Superuser and to your particular question already given in the previous comments, here is a QA frequently referenced for people asking why their beginner Kali questions were poorly received: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me#399627

@joel - Those were critical details that were necessary to troubleshoot your question.  You could [edit] your question and indicate the close reason has been addressed, and the community will vote to reopen if that is that the case. It sounds like you now know what the password is. "Ignoring people because they are inexperienced is elitist and rude. " - We did not ignore you. You failed to provide enough information to help you, so your question was closed, until the question was modified and reopened

Edit your question to contain enough information to answer your question.

When you first posted your question, I went to the Kali Pre-build Virtual Machines link and clicked on the docs link for Recommended VirtualBox. The first page of the docs link states "Remember the default login is kali for the user and kali for the password!". You posted you tried "kali/kali". So I agree the question needs details like where you download Kali and not doing so make the question lack clarity.

No, that is your job. Including basic information such as the model computer, the host operating system, links to where you downloaded software and such are your responsibility. Users donate their time to answer questions. In my case, I spent a short amount of time, then decided to take a pass on helping. Other who may have known the answer may have done the same.

Absolutely. You could also be a grandma not knowing what computers are and be trying to ask about Kali Linux, but that doesn't mean your question will be a good fit here. It also doesn't mean people here will hold your hand and explain to you how everything works from A to Z. You somehow fail to understand how this website works - perhaps because you still haven't read the rules and guides. It might be the time to do so instead of contuing to waste time on nothing: https://superuser.com/help Help is offered, but making it as easy as possible to help you is expected first.

joel: Where were you shamed? I would assume any down votes came for the reason they exist. Many of the users who voted to close posted comment(s) afterwards with explanations. In fact, you were told. You posted "people told me that if I asked this question I should use a different distro". That was not "people", that was one user. That user did not vote to close your question and just offered a personal opinion. You can look at the timeline if you want to see voted to close your question.

You don't come here and have demands, you respect the way things work and try to fit in. That's how the world generally works. Else people don't like it and downvote you, prevent your content from getting popular b e.g. closing it or "shame you" by telling you what to definitely avoid doing in the future. I have no idea what you're trying to do now, but you're the one who'd I'd describe much more by "shaming" - insulting the entire community whose ways you don't try to follow and respect. That has no reasonable goal.


”So why ignore and even downvote beginner questions about Kali Linux?”

You are not obligated to get an upvote for a question or to get an explanation for a downvote. You are not required to have an explanation for either action.
That said, Kali Linux questions are often from beginners who have no idea what Linux is or how it works. They typically download and install Kali Linux to be “l33t.”
So when a question comes up with Kali Linux, pretty much everyone rolls their eyes and mumbles to themselves, “One of those guys again!” and then decides to downvote and even vote to close the question pretty much immediately.
Here, read up on the issue here on our sister site, Unix & Linux SE:

Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?

You say further:

“Ignoring/downvoting people because they're "beginners" is going to discourage them from using Linux, confuse them and make them feel negatively about the Linux community.”

Let’s set some things straight: Kali Linux is not the only Linux version out there. If you feel hurt a confused that you are being called out on using Kali Linux, you ignore the fact that you don’t know what you are doing.
Regarding the core of your question regarding the password:

“The password is osboxes.org and this is for all distros that you download using the link from the Virtual Box website.”

Good lord! Without you telling us you downloaded the image from osboxes.org we could never have helped you. In fact, the question was answered by you yourself!
Did you finally figure it out by yourself? Great! Then the question doesn’t need to exist any longer, right? What are you complaining about; in fact just go ahead and delete it at this point. It is an utterly useless question.
